# ConnectionError while downloading a file using requests library

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to download one dataset from UCI ML repository in Python. Here is my code:

```
import requests

zip_url = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00228/smsspamcollection.zip'
r = requests.get(zip_url)
```

But, after running the code I get the following error. What is the reason and how to resolve it?

`ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='archive.ics.uci.edu', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /ml/machine-learning-databases/00228/smsspamcollection.zip (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x11a3c15c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 53] Software caused connection abort',))`

Comment: I executed this without a problem. Did you maybe run it in a loop?

Comment: @BoarGules No, not in a loop. Just the mentioned code raise this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking into this similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013220/max-retries-exceeded-with-url) and [this issue](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1198).
Also i would try to get a connection to other urls using requests.get and see if that works.
Also you could try to download the file using cmd-line tools like wget or a webbrowser from the same machine to see if you can get a connection to the server.

Comment: Thanks. The looping idea presented in the link did not work for me. I tested another url from a different host but got the same problem. Downloading from web-browser was OK.

Comment: Does your web browser have a proxy configured?

Comment: Oh! I got what was wrong with my program. There was an application running in the background refusing other application to access the internet! Thanks for your help.