# Flower Http Api get Celery task details

Tags: python, celery, flower

I have a working celery flower project. 
Now I want some celery failed task details using `flower http api`, but  my celery is using `--basic-auth` for authentication and when I make a request at `flower http api` on `http://localhost:5555/api/tasks` it timeouts and does not show any results.

I did not understand if this is an auth problem or something else. I look to flower docs but i did not get any idea. Thanks for you time. Below is the code that is not working for me.

```
import requests

params = (('state', 'FAILURE'),('limit', '5'),)

requests.get('http://localhost:5555/api/tasks', params=params)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then you should make your request with your credentials:

1. Import [`HTTPBasicAuth`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication) (since you are using `--basic-auth`):

   ```
   from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
   ```
2. Make an authenticated request:

   ```
   requests.get(
       'http://localhost:5555/api/tasks', 
       auth=HTTPBasicAuth('your_user', 'your_pass'), 
       params=params
   )
   ```

Good luck :)

Comment: thanks for quick response but its give me error requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='139.172.59.25', port=5555): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/tasks?state=FAILURE&limit=5 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f73ccf4f7d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))

Comment: @ManishYadav That seems to be a different issue. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013220/max-retries-exceeded-with-url?answertab=votes#tab-top and at this requests issue: https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1198