# Python automatic login with Requests and Beautifulsoup from list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

trying to learn Python at the moment and am currently developing a small program which imports a list of login pages and tries your username/password automatically on them. Unfortunately I'm running into some errors and can't quite figure it out what the issue is. Please excuse the messy code by the way, still working on it.

Here's my source:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import_file_path = input('Enter the path of the list to be tested: ')

export_file_path = input('Enter the path of where we should export the websites that worked to:: ')
with open(import_file_path, 'r') as panels:
    panel_list = []
    for line in panels:
        panel_list.append(line)

x = 0

for panel in panel_list:
    url = requests.get(panel)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")
    forms = soup.find_all("form")
    action = soup.find('form').get('action')

    values = { 
    soup.find_all("input")[0].get("name") : "user",
    soup.find_all("input")[1].get("name") : "pass"
    }


    if "http://" or "https://" not in action:
        action = 'http://' + action

    r = requests.post(action, data=values)
    print(r.content)
    x += 1
```

Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
Enter the path of the website to be tested: list.txt
Enter the path of where we should export the vuln panels to: exit.txt
http://http://localhost/admin.php/vuln.php
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 60, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 743, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 357, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 166, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x038B9070>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='http', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: //localhost/admin.php/vuln.php (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x038B9070>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scan.py", line 35, in <module>
    r = requests.post(action, data=values)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 112, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 508, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='http', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: //localhost/admin.php/vuln.php (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x038B9070>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))
```

Comment: You should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013220/max-retries-exceeded-with-url

Comment: @Ricardo The issue was that the code was using /vuln.php as the URL. I have a new issue now, haha. I have updated the OP. Regarding the new error: on line 36, should I be using the action from the source or the actual login page URL? When I use the login page URL I get no errors, but it returns the source of the login page url so I'm not sure if it's actually logging in.

Comment: Ayou really sure that the login form is the first one on all pages mentioned by your text file ?

You should check if the "action" form attribute is an absolute or relative URL. In case of relative URL.
If it's relative, rebuild an absolute URL with the one of the actual page and the relative one you got fom the form attribute.
The `urljoin` function of stdlib `urllib.parse` is your friend.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin

Comment: BTW, the "gaierror" means that there's no such host.

Comment: @glenfant I figured out the issue, but ran into another.

Basically, my code was returning http://example.com/login.php/action.php, but I have no idea how to fix it other than finding a way to remove /login.php , but that link will vary from site to site.

Comment: Please be clearer, what  in that example what is the precise URL of the page that publishes the form, and what is the RAW VALUE of the "action" attribute of this form ?