# Catching SSLError due to unsecure URL with requests in Python?

Tags: python, ssl, error-handling, python-requests

I have a list of a few thousand URLs and noticed one of them is throwing as `SSLError` when passed into `requests.get()`. Below is my attempt to work around this using both a [solution suggested in this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013220/max-retries-exceeded-with-url/47475019#47475019) as well as a failed attempt to catch the error with a "try & except" block using `ssl.SSLError`:

```
url = 'https://archyworldys.com/lidl-recalls-puff-pastry/'

session = requests.Session()
retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
session.mount('http://', adapter)
session.mount('https://', adapter)

try:
    response = session.get(url,allow_redirects=False,verify=True)
except ssl.SSLError:
    pass
```

The error returned at the very end is:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='archyworldys.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /lidl-recalls-puff-pastry/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

When I opened the URL in Chrome, I get a "Not Secure" / "Privacy Error" that blocks the webpage. However, if I try the URL with HTTP instead of HTTPS (e.g. 'http://archyworldys.com/lidl-recalls-puff-pastry/') it works just fine in my browser. Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-sslerror), setting `verify` to `False` solves the problem, but I prefer to find a more secure work-around.

**While I understand a simple solution would be to remove the URL from my data, I'm trying to find a solution that let's me proceed (e.g. if in a `for loop`) by simply skipping this bad URL and moving on the next one.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Requests throwing SSLError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-sslerror)

Comment: The work around won't help because the SSL connection will always fail because the server certificate expired 2 years ago. I'd say that that web site no longer supports SSL. Looking at its content, it's probably safe to fall back to an insecure connection, i.e. `http://...`.

Answer (score 5):

The error I get when running your code is:

> requests.exceptions.SSLError:
>   [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
>   (_ssl.c:645)

Based on this one needs to catch `requests.exceptions.SSLError` and not `ssl.SSLError`, i.e.:

```
try:
    response = session.get(url,allow_redirects=False,verify=True)
except requests.exceptions.SSLError:
    pass
```

While it looks like the error you get is different this is probably due the code you show being not exactly the code you are running. Anyway, look at the exact error message you get and figure out from this which exception exactly to catch. You might also try to catch a more general exception like this and by doing this get the exact Exception class you need to catch:

```
try:
    response = session.get(url,allow_redirects=False,verify=True)
except Exception as x:
    print(type(x),x)
    pass
```