# SSLError when requesting from opentdb

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

### The problem

When requesting from [opentdb](https://opentdb.com/), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trivia.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(requests.get('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1'))
  File "/Users/edl/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/edl/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/edl/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/edl/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/edl/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 506, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='opentdb.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api.php?amount=1 (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:600)'),))
```

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013220/max-retries-exceeded-with-url) as well as the [issues page on github](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues) but none of the solutions are working. Requesting from other sites works completely fine on my computer, so I am not sure what is wrong.

#### Further weirdness

However, running this code in js gives no errors, so I am not sure what is wrong with `requests`.

```js
function get(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url);
    req.onload = () => req.status === 200 ? resolve(req.response) : reject(req.statusText);
    req.onerror = () => reject("Network Error");
    req.send();
  });
}

get('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1').then(console.log)
```

#### Even FURTHER weirdness

When running the same code in [repl.it](https://repl.it/@Maydoh1239/Opentdb), everything works with no problems. Is it because of my computer that this isn't working? I'm not sure why it works from repl.it but not my own computer.

### Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:

```
import requests

print(requests.get('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1'))
```

### More information:

Using `python 3.4.4`

Info about `requests`:

```
Name: requests
Version: 2.18.4
Summary: Python HTTP for Humans.
Home-page: http://python-requests.org
Author: Kenneth Reitz
Author-email: me@kennethreitz.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /Users/edl/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages
Requires: urllib3, certifi, idna, chardet
```

Comment: When using javascript promises, errors will just be silently ignored if you don't add a catch handler. Try `get('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1').then(console.log).catch(console.error)` and you should get an error message in the console if the get request fails for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As taken from [this issue](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/4246), the solution is to install `pyopenssl`, which I apparently did not have. Running

```
pip3 install --user pyopenssl
```

Fixed all the errors. Still not sure exactly why this is. If someone could explain why `pyopenssl` fixed it, that would be great. Thanks!