# Connection Error using Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

```
link="https://report-abc.com/crp/cdo"


node_id_1="00163E0F0D0C1ED895"

params={'id':node_id_1,
        'list':'142',
        'queue': 'gen',
        'type': 'crp_stat'
       }

headers = {'accept': 'application/json'}


req_obj= requests.get(link, params=params,headers=headers)
print(req_obj.url)
print(req_obj.status_code)
```

However while it was working yesterday and I was getting the data albeit in html format instead of json. today it is throwing me connection error:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='report-abc.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /crp/cdo?queue=gen&list=142&id=00163E0F0D0C1ED895&type=crp_stat (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x107362a90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))
```

I have tried the suggestions mentioned in this stack overflow question including installing pyopenssl:

[Max retries exceeded with URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013220/max-retries-exceeded-with-url)

But it doesn't seem to help.

Any idea would be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known`. are you sure that `node_id` is correct?

Comment: Yes it is. It was working two days ago