# How to filter classes from COCO Dataset?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, object-detection, yolo

I would like to train a yolo model with the COCO dataset. As there are more than 80 classes, how can I filter it? I just need the classes person and car.

Answer (score 3):

For easy and simple way, follow these steps :

- Modify (or copy for backup) the `coco.names` file in `darknet\data\coco.names`
- Delete all other classes except person and car
- Modify your cfg file (e.g. `yolov3.cfg`), change the 3 classes on line 610, 696, 783 from 80 to 2
- Change the 3 filters in cfg file on line 603, 689, 776 from 255 to (classes+5)x3 = 21
- Run the detector `./darknet detector test cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights data/person.jpg`

For more advance way you can use this repo to create yolo datasets based on voc, coco or open images. https://github.com/holger-prause/yolo_utils

Also refer to this : [How can I download a specific part of Coco Dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100191/how-can-i-download-a-specific-part-of-coco-dataset)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [PyCoco API](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/tree/master/PythonAPI) to work with the COCO dataset. With this library, filtering classes from the dataset is so easy!

```
# Define the classes (out of the 81) which you want to see. Others will not be shown.
filterClasses = ['person', 'dog']

# Fetch class IDs only corresponding to the filterClasses
catIds = coco.getCatIds(catNms=filterClasses) 
# Get all images containing the above Category IDs
imgIds = coco.getImgIds(catIds=catIds)
print("Number of images containing all the  classes:", len(imgIds))

# load and display a random image
img = coco.loadImgs(imgIds[np.random.randint(0,len(imgIds))])[0]
I = io.imread('{}/images/{}/{}'.format(dataDir,dataType,img['file_name']))/255.0
```

I have recently written an entire post on [exploring and manipulating the COCO dataset](https://towardsdatascience.com/master-the-coco-dataset-for-semantic-image-segmentation-part-1-of-2-732712631047). Do have a look.

Comment: How do you import pycocotools?

Comment: I just tried  `filterClasses = ['person', 'dog']
catIds = coco.getCatIds(catNms=filterClasses)` and got `KeyError: 'categories'`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this these days is to use [`fiftyone`](https://fiftyone.ai) which is recommended on the COCO website to [download, visualize, and evaluate the dataset including any subset of classes](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/integrations/coco.html).

```py
import fiftyone as fo
import fiftyone.zoo as foz

#
# Only the required images will be downloaded (if necessary).
# By default, only detections are loaded
#

dataset = foz.load_zoo_dataset(
    "coco-2017",
    splits=["validation","train"],
    classes=["person", "car"],
    # max_samples=50,
)

# Visualize the dataset in the FiftyOne App
session = fo.launch_app(dataset)
```

[image]

You can also use it to [convert the dataset to YOLO format](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/user_guide/export_datasets.html#yolov5dataset) and to [train models](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/integrations/lightning_flash.html) directly on the dataset.

```py
# Export the dataset in YOLO format
export_dir = "/path/for/yolov5-dataset"
label_field = "ground_truth"

dataset.export(
    export_dir=export_dir,
    dataset_type=fo.types.YOLOv5Dataset,
    label_field=label_field,
)
```

To install:

```
pip install fiftyone
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way you have to filter classes without retrain model on Coco dataset is to make a check on detection output to avoid to draw a box for useless classes, but the model will continue to detect all classes in background.