# How to download specific labels/images from tensorflow-datasets

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm currently using the coco/2017 dataset for some use in tf.keras transferred learning

I am aware that you can download the full dataset using the code bellow:

```py
(raw_train, raw_validation, raw_test), metadata = tfds.load(
                                        'coco/2017',
                                        split=list(splits),
                                        with_info=True,
                                        as_supervised=True)
```

How would I do this if I only wanted to extract the 'persons' images and labels. Instead of the full dataset?

Comment: I think your question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100191/how-can-i-download-a-specific-part-of-coco-dataset

Comment: That way is specific to the coco dataset libraries. I'm looking for a way of doing it through tensorflow-datasets