# Expand short urls in python using requests library

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, user-agent

I have a large number of short URLs and I want to expand them. I found somewhere online (I missed the source) the following code:

```
short_url = "t.co/NHBbLlfCaa"
r = requests.get(short_url)
if r.status_code == 200:
    print("Actual url:%s" % r.url)
```

It works perfectly. But I get this error when I ping the same server for many times:

> urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
>   HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.fatlossadvice.pw', port=80): Max retries
>   exceeded with url:
>   /TIPS/KILLED-THAT-TREADMILL-WORKOUT-WORD-TO-TIMMY-GACQUIN.ASP (Caused
>   by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno
>   11004] getaddrinfo failed',))

I tried many solutions like the set here: [Max retries exceeded with URL in requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013220/max-retries-exceeded-with-url-in-requests), but nothing worked.

I was thinking about another solution, which is to pass an useragent in the request, and each time I change it randomly (using a large number of useragents):

```
user_agent_list = [
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36',
    ]

r = requests.get(short_url, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent_list[np.random.randint(0, len(user_agent_list))]})
if r.status_code == 200:
    print("Actual url:%s" % r.url)
```

My problem is that **r.url** always return the short url instead of the long one (the expanded one).

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean "short url"? Are you using url shortener service, like e.g. tinyurl?

Comment: @AndrejKesely, I added an example. I wasn't able to add it with "https://" , stackoverflow terms of use prevents me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the error by adding `allow_redirects=False` to `requests.get()` method to prevent redirecting to page that doesn't exist (and thus raising the error). You have to examine the header sent by server yourself (replace `XXXX` by `https`, remove spaces):

```
import requests

short_url = ["XXXX t.co /namDL4YHYu",
 'XXXX t.co /MjvmV',
 'XXXX t.co /JSjtxfaxRJ',
 'XXXX t.co /xxGSANSE8K',
 'XXXX t.co /ZRhf5gWNQg']

for url in short_url:
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    try:
        print(url, r.headers['location'])
    except KeyError:
        print(url, "Page doesn't exist!")
```

Prints:

```
XXXX t.co/namDL4YHYu http://gottimechillinaround.tumblr.com/post/133931725110/tip-672
XXXX t.co/MjvmV Page doesn't exist!
XXXX t.co/JSjtxfaxRJ http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rE693eNyyss
XXXX t.co/xxGSANSE8K http://www.losefattips.pw/Tips/My-stretch-before-and-after-my-workout-is-just-as-important-to-me-as-my-workout.asp
XXXX .co/ZRhf5gWNQg http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3OK1P9GzDPM
```

Comment: It doesn't work for many URL's, like: XXXX:// t.co /namDL4YHYu !

Comment: @Ghanem It works for me, it prints `http://gottimechillinaround.tumblr.com/post/133931725110/tip-672`

Comment: Sorry, maybe I copied incorrect one. Try these: XXXXs:// t.co/MjvmV, XXXX:// t.co/JSjtxfaxRJ, XXXXs:// t.co/xxGSANSE8K, XXXXs:// t.co/ZRhf5gWNQg

Comment: @Ghanem The `t.co/MjvmV` dosn't contain key `location` because the page doesn't exist. When I put it into the firefox, it's error page.