# Python:requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(),Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python, web-crawler

I use python3 requests module to access api of my company. After several thousand request(I need million s of request), encountered a problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 83, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] xxxxxx.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 357, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 166, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000252463B7588>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] xxxxxx
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='uf-api6.ksord.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /xxxxxx/get/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000252463B7588>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] xxxxxx',))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/pyworkspace/pycharm/eb/analysis.py", line 141, in <module>
    local_req()
  File "D:/pyworkspace/pycharm/eb/analysis.py", line 97, in local_req
    res_api = request_pika(hdid, label)
  File "D:\pyworkspace\pycharm\eb\es_and_pika_utils.py", line 21, in request_pika
    res = requests.post(url, json=data, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json", 'Connection': 'close'})
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 112, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 508, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='api.xxxxxx.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2/feature/get/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000252463B7588>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] xxxxxx',))
```

Here is my code:

```
res = requests.post(url, json=data, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json", 'Connection': 'close'})
res.connection.close()
res.close()
```

1,In code above , I have close every connection and do not let it keep alive. 
2,And I have adjust `TcpTimedWaitDelay` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters` to 10. 
3,I do not need proxy because the api do not ban the same IP.
4.My computer have enough memmory.
How to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Max retries exceeded with URL in requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013220/max-retries-exceeded-with-url-in-requests)

Comment: No. I thought it's port collection. I went to linux to run this code, passed.