# 'str' object has no attribute 'text' in BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to login to a website using python Request for an automation purpose. And I'm getting an error as `'str' object has no attribute 'text'`

My code is

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup



logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log',level=logging.INFO)
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'
}
def post_request_curl(data):
    try:   
           with requests.Session() as s:
              login_data=data['login_details']
              r = s.get(url=data['url'], headers=headers)
              soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
              login_data['form_build_id'] = soup.find_all('input', attrs={'name': 'form_build_id'})['value']
              r = s.post(url=data['url'], data=login_data, headers=headers)

              return r  
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error('Error occurred ' + str(e))
```

Comment: add the full code please

Comment: I have posted all code

Comment: error at which line?

Comment: ya. i dont see any .text

Comment: soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

Comment: it return  error as `'str' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: while calling the fucntion, what did you give for data

Comment: {'url': 'https://www.codechef.com/', 'login_details': {'op': 'Login', 'name': 'edward', 'form_id': 'new_login_form', 'pass': 'wrongpassword'}, 'fields_in_response': [], 'fields_in_main_page': []}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log',level=logging.INFO)
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'
}
def post_request_curl(data):
    try:   
           with requests.Session() as s:
              login_data=data['login_details']
              r = s.get(url=data['url'], headers=headers)
              soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
              login_data['form_build_id'] = soup.find_all('input', attrs={'name': 'form_build_id'})['value']
              r = s.post(url=data['url'], data=login_data, headers=headers)

              return r  
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error('Error occurred ' + str(e))
```

Comment: `Error occurred HTTPConnectionPool(host='http', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: //dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/create (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff7920a3390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))`

Comment: What happened here is thatcodechef.com server refuses your connection (you're sending too many requests from same ip address in short period of time)

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013220/max-retries-exceeded-with-url-in-requests

Comment: I need to implement this login using curl in any site. Could you please suggest a method

Comment: will the library selenium help you?