# Requests retry with verify=false if SSLError

Tags: python, python-requests

I'using `Requests` to scrape webpages and have encounter in a couple of instances issues with the website SSL certificate. I would like to implement a logic whereas the first request is done with `verify=true` but if there is a `SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]` then it retries with `verify=false`.

Here is my initial code, what I'm struggling with is catching the error and passing it to the `retry` function.

```
#MAKE FIRST REQUEST
r = requests_retry_session().get(url,  headers=headers, timeout=10)
#RETRY FUNCTION
def requests_retry_session(
        retries=5,
        backoff_factor= 10,
        status_forcelist=(500, 502, 504),
        session=None,
):
    session = session or requests.Session()
    retry = Retry(
        total=retries,
        read=retries,
        connect=retries,
        backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
        status_forcelist=status_forcelist,
    )
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
#IF SSLERROR set verify to false
    session.verify = False
    return session
```

Comment: Wrap the code inside ``try:.. except:..`` block and retry by setting verify to ``False`` on error.

Comment: From the security point of view it does not make any difference if you fall back to an unverified connection or if you allow unverified connections in the first place.

Comment: @KlausD. That's very interesting. I've been reading that you should use an unverified connection only if really necessary. So I was thinking to use it as fallback instead as per default. Why are they saying that if there is no difference? Thanks

Comment: If the connection is attacked an SSLError will be the result. Falling back to an unverified connection then will allow the attack to be successful.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks @KlausD.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Max retries exceeded with URL in requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013220/max-retries-exceeded-with-url-in-requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter Bengtsson answered this [in a comment on his site here](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/best-practice-with-retries-with-requests#cbec41e):

```
from requests.exceptions import SSLError
session = requests.retry_session()
try:
   r = session.get(url)
except SSLError:
   r = session.get(url, verify=False)
```

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to a simple `r = session.get(url, verify=False)`.