# HTTPS connection error with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

I'm trying to run a simple requests code but it's giving me HTTPS connection error.... Please help

```
import requests
x=requests.get('https://www.google.ca')
print(x.status_code)
```

Here's the error message:

```
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/129881249/Desktop/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    x=requests.get('https://www.google.ca')

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.ca', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000015CCB7B4388>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))
```

Answer (score 0):

please refer to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013220/max-retries-exceeded-with-url-in-requests) link and try again now, perhaps you made too many requests. You can also try using a proxy to connect, change the firewall settings ,or try a different computer.