# HTTPSConnectionPool(host='site.api.espn.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python, python-requests

I received the following error when I was crawling the espn football website to crawl the score information:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='site.api.espn.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /apis/site/v2/sports/soccer/scorepanel?lang=en®ion=us&calendartype=whitelist&limit=100&showAirings=true&dates=20201224&tz=America%2FNew_York (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection
```

Below is my code:

```
url = "https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/soccer/scorepanel?lang=en&region=us&calendartype=whitelist&limit=100&showAirings=true&dates=20201224&tz=America%2FNew_York"
warnings.simplefilter('ignore',InsecureRequestWarning)
session = requests.Session()
session.keep_alive = False
data = session.get(url, verify=False, headers={'Connection':'close'})
data.close()
print('Connection close.')
```

Comment: Works on my machine, check you network connection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Max retries exceeded with URL in requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013220/max-retries-exceeded-with-url-in-requests)

Comment: My machine has been confirmed.