# How to download as a Pandas Data Frame tabel from Wikipedia in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I would like to download table from Wikipedia.org from this link as a Pandas Data Frame to Jupyter Lab: https://pl.wikisource.org/wiki/Polskie_powiaty_wed%C5%82ug_kodu_TERYT

There is only one table and not complicated, how can I do that in Python ?

Answer (score 1):

**Type 1:**

Just use `pandas` method `pd.read_html` method and from extract what so ever `df` you want

```
import pandas as pd
res=pd.read_html("https://pl.wikisource.org/wiki/Polskie_powiaty_wed%C5%82ug_kodu_TERYT")
df=res[3]
```

**Type 2:**

you can use both `request` and `bs4` module to find table and parse data to `pandas` method

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res=requests.get("https://pl.wikisource.org/wiki/Polskie_powiaty_wed%C5%82ug_kodu_TERYT")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")

data=soup.find_all("table")[3]
df=pd.read_html(str(data))
df[0]
```

Output:

```
    Nazwa powiatu   TERYT
0   aleksandrowski  04 01
1   augustowski     20 01
.   .....          ..
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to scrape HTML using requests library, after you need to search on tag using library (i use BeautifulSoup).
The code is similar to this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://pl.wikisource.org/wiki/Polskie_powiaty_wed%C5%82ug_kodu_TERYT"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find("div", {"id":"mw-content-text"}).find("table",{"border":1}).find_all("td")
namelist = [results[i].text for i in range(0,len(results),2)]
numberlist = [results[i].text.strip('\n') for i in range(1,len(results),2)]
```

Then it returns a value of type string. Or you can get all values ​​as a list. It's very simple to convert to pandas after.

Comment: I have error like below using your code: ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pl.wikisource.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /wiki/Polskie_powiaty_wed%C5%82ug_kodu_TERYT (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fedd96f6a10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable'))

Comment: Could you try answers on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013220/max-retries-exceeded-with-url-in-requests

Comment: Hmm there is many answers, could you write the best and modify your answe? Because I am not able to change it

Comment: I edited the code now its work well. But i can't fix your error you should fix it yourself.