# How to increase PSAW Max Retries

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, reddit, praw

I keep receiving the following error when trying to collect a large data from pushshift.io using PSAW.

Exception: Unable to connect to pushshift.io. Max retries exceeded.

How can I increase the "max retries" so that this won't happen?

```
my_reddit_submissions=api.search_submissions(before=int(end_epoch.timestamp()),
                                            post_hint='image',
                                            filter=['id','full_link','title', 'url', 'subreddit', 'author_fullname'],
                                            limit = frequency
                                            )


for submission_x in my_reddit_submissions:
           data_new=data_new.append(submission_x.d_, ignore_index=True)
```

BTW, my code works fine till a point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should take a look at this question *[Might help]* : [Max retries exceeded with URL in requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013220/max-retries-exceeded-with-url-in-requests)

This Exception Is Raised When ***The Server Actively refuses to communicate*** with you. This May happen if you ***request too many times to the server*** in a **short period of time**.

To **OverCome This**, you should **wait for a few seconds before retrying**

Here is an example :

```py
import time
import requests

with requests.Session() as session:
    while 1: # Infinite Loop used to send infinite requests to the server without waiting time
        try:
            response = session.get("https://www.example.com")           
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            response.status_code = "Connection Refused By The Server"
            time.sleep(2) # Sleeping For 2 seconds to resolve the server overload error
        print(response.status_code)
```