# Max retries exceeded with url error Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests, digital-ocean

I'm trying to connect to a website with the code below. There is no problem on Heroku. But I am getting error in DigitalOcean.

Code:

```
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"}

def web():
  rq = requests.get("https://myurl.com/gts?search=word", headers = headers)
  print(rq)
```

The error I get in DigitalOcean:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='myurl.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /gts?search=word (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa364a89690>, 'Connection to myurl.com timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))
```

What I've done and failed:

I added code verify=False, disabled firewall from console. And I tried to access the site from the console with the "curl -I myurl.com" command. All failed.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Max retries exceeded with URL in requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013220/max-retries-exceeded-with-url-in-requests)

Comment: Isn't this caused by `myurl.com` web server firewall? Digital Oceans IP can just be blocked by it. Without exact url is this issue difficult to debug. Also it's not clear whether `myurl.com` is your website or not.

Comment: @sahasrara62 I saw this thread but it didn't help.

Comment: @FN_ This happens only on sozluk.gov.tr. Myurl.com is actually sozluk.gov.tr.

Comment: @Emir I tried to run `curl` or even your code snippet on a Digital Ocean hosted machine. Both worked fine. It seems to me that you are having bad luck and your IP is blocked, because your code is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the issue is not caused by a bug in your code, but rather by firewall (or other rules) on the remote server side (`sozluk.gov.tr`).

I have tried to run `curl -I https://sozluk.gov.tr` and also your snippet on my local and also remote (Digital Ocean hosted) VM - **both worked fine**.

You mentioned that `curl` command from console (I assume remove VM console) did not work. This indicates, that the issue is on the network - rather than code - level.

---

I recommend to spin new VM in different region (*to get IP from different IP pool*) or use some kind of a proxy which is not blocked by remote server. You can check available regions (datacenters) on [this link](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/platform/availability-matrix/#available-datacenters).

---

Responses

```
user@do-server:~$ curl -I https://sozluk.gov.tr
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 18 Feb 2023 11:18:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 108975
Last-Modified: Fri, 13 Jan 2023 12:38:15 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
ETag: "63c150b7-1a9af"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

```
user@do-server:~$ python3
Python 3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"}
>>> requests.get("https://sozluk.gov.tr/gts?search=word", headers = headers)
<Response [200]>
```