# How do I resolve HTTPSConnectionPool error, Max retries exceeded with url in python?

Tags: python, django, python-requests

requests didn't work as expected

```
    def post(self, request):
        base_url = os.environ.get('AUTH_URL', 'http://localhost')
        # Make a POST request to the authentication endpoint with the payload

        headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) "
                          "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36",
            'accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }

        json_data = {
            'username': os.environ.get("GARAJ_USERNAME", "admin"),
            'password': os.environ.get("GARAJ_PASSWORD", "admin123"),
        }
        response = requests.post(base_url + '/api/token/', json=json_data, headers=headers)

        # Check the response status code
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            # Extract the JWT token from the response
            jwt_token_access = data['access']
            # Use the JWT token for subsequent API requests
            headers['Authorization'] = f'Bearer {jwt_token_access}'
            auth_url = base_url + '/api/boshqarma/avto/'
            response = requests.get(auth_url, headers=headers)

            for x in response.json()['results']:
                if x["davlat_raqami"] == request.data['avto_raqami']:
                    boshqarma = x["boshqarma"]
                    response = requests.get(base_url + f'/api/boshqarma/boshqarma/{boshqarma}/', headers=headers)
                    tuman = response.json()['tuman']
                    response = requests.get(base_url + f'/api/boshqarma/bolim/{tuman}/', headers=headers)
                    tuman = response.json()['tuman']
                    tuman = Tuman.objects.get(tuman_nomi=tuman)
                    data = {'tuman_id': tuman.id}
                    response = Response(data)
                    return response
            else:
                return Response("Xato avto raqam")

            # Make additional API requests with the headers containing the JWT token

        else:
            return Response(response)
```

This code block works on using localhost but did't work when it is on server,but returns below error.I manage both servers client and host server too.
ConnectionError at /api/check-car/
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='example.uz', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/token/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f3d48892f50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Max retries exceeded with URL in requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013220/max-retries-exceeded-with-url-in-requests)

Comment: @sahasrara62 I tried all answers there but it seems none of them works on my case

Comment: might be related to server, test with a simple 1 request and see if you are able to make it or not

Answer (score 0):

So, basically my both services client and host were running on the same server on different subdomains, using http instead of https and adding host's local IP address to client's /etc/hosts and binding it to host subdomain resolved the issue.