# How to handle exception "error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am a Python newbie. I have a script that I'm running on google app engine. It uses urllib3 to talk to an api. It runs perfectly on my computer but it fails and gives me an

> "error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by
>   the remote host"

I've done some research and the best answer seems to be exception handling. How would I do this?

```
for row in rows:
    address = row['emailaddress']
    status = row['status']
    location = row['location']

    if status != 'Active':
        status = 'Inactive'

    payload = '{xxx}'            

    r = http.urlopen('POST', url, body=payload, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814802/python-errno-10054-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-h

Comment: Why are you using urllib3 connection pooling won't work on appengine unless you are using sockets/billing.   If you want some level of concurrency (you example sure does) then you should consider using async requests  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code with a 'try and catch' and use [async requests](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests) (as Tim noted), example:

```
rpc = urlfetch.create_rpc()
urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc, 'http://www.google.com/')

# ... do other things ...
try:
    result = rpc.get_result()
    if result.status_code == 200:
        text = result.content
        self.response.write(text)
    else:
        self.response.status_int = result.status_code
        self.response.write('URL returned status code {}'.format(
            result.status_code))
except urlfetch.DownloadError:
    self.response.status_int = 500
    self.response.write('Error fetching URL')
```