# Rabbitmq error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, rabbitmq, kombu

I am using Kombu in Python to consume a durable RabbitMQ queue.

There is only one consumer consuming the queue in Windows. This consumer produces the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\consumer_windows.py", line 66, in <module>
    message.ack()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kombu\message.py", line 88, in ack
    self.channel.basic_ack(self.delivery_tag)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\amqp\channel.py", line 1584, in basic_ack
    self._send_method((60, 80), args)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\amqp\abstract_channel.py", line 56, in _send_method
    self.channel_id, method_sig, args, content,
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\amqp\method_framing.py", line 221, in write_method
    write_frame(1, channel, payload)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\amqp\transport.py", line 182, in write_frame
    frame_type, channel, size, payload, 0xce,
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda2\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

There are at most 500 messages in the queue at any one time. Each message is small in size however it is a task and takes up to 10 minutes to complete (although it usually takes less then 5 mins per message).

I have tried restarting the consumer, RabbitMQ server and deleting the queue however the error still persists.

I've seen [this question](http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2010-February/006197.html) however [the answer](http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2010-February/006210.html) is from 2010 and my rabbitmq.log has different entries:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 24-Apr-2016::08:26:20 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.6716.384> (192.168.X.X:59602 -> 192.168.Y.X:5672):
{writer,send_failed,{error,timeout}}
```

There were no recent events in the rabbitmq-sasl.log.

Why is this error happening and how can I prevent it from occurring?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?

Comment: @bmjjr Unfortunately not

Comment: also looking for a solution

Comment: I get similar problem and still searching for solution.Anyone have solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: \[Errno 10054\] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814802/python-errno-10054-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-h)

Answer (score 1):

I'm still looking for an answer. In the meantime I restart the connection to my rabbit server:

```
while True:
    try:
​
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
        channel = connection.channel() # start a channel
        channel.queue_declare(queue=amqp_q, durable=True) # Declare a queue
        ...
​
    except pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
        print('connection closed... and restarted')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with MySQL server which was hosted...
I came to understand that it happened if we open the connection for a long time or unmodified for a long time..
If your program opens the DB or anything until the whole program runs make it in a such a way that it opens the DB writes everything and closes and repeats

I don't know what exactly rabbitmq is but I think the error you wrote as title may be for this reason

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error (using pure PIKA library) and trying to connect to a Rabbitmq broker through Amazon MQ.

The problem resolved when setting up correctly the ssl configuration.

Please check full blog post here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/amazon-mq-rabbitmq-pika.html

### Core snippets that I used:

#### Define Pika Client:

```py
import ssl
import pika

class BasicPikaClient:

    def __init__(self, rabbitmq_broker_id, rabbitmq_user, rabbitmq_password, region):

        # SSL Context for TLS configuration of Amazon MQ for RabbitMQ
        ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
        ssl_context.set_ciphers('ECDHE+AESGCM:!ECDSA')

        url = f"amqps://{rabbitmq_user}:{rabbitmq_password}@{rabbitmq_broker_id}.mq.{region}.amazonaws.com:5671"
        parameters = pika.URLParameters(url)
        parameters.ssl_options = pika.SSLOptions(context=ssl_context)

        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
```

#### Producer:

```py
from basicClient import BasicPikaClient

class BasicMessageSender(BasicPikaClient):

    def declare_queue(self, queue_name, durable):
        print(f"Trying to declare queue({queue_name})...")
        self.channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name, durable=durable)

    def send_message(self, exchange, routing_key, body):
        channel = self.connection.channel()
        channel.basic_publish(exchange=exchange,
                              routing_key=routing_key,
                              body=body)
        print(f"Sent message. Exchange: {exchange}, Routing Key: {routing_key}, Body: {body}")

    def close(self):
        self.channel.close()
        self.connection.close()
```

#### Calling Producer:

```py
# Initialize Basic Message Sender which creates a connection
# and channel for sending messages.
basic_message_sender = BasicMessageSender(
    credentials["broker_id"],
    credentials["username"],
    credentials['password'],
    credentials['region']
)

# Declare a queue
basic_message_sender.declare_queue("q_name", durable=True)

# Send a message to the queue.
basic_message_sender.send_message(exchange="", routing_key="q_name", body=b'Hello World 2!')

# Close connections.
basic_message_sender.close()
```

#### Define Consumer:

```py
class BasicMessageReceiver(BasicPikaClient):

    def get_message(self, queue):
        method_frame, header_frame, body = self.channel.basic_get(queue)
        if method_frame:
            print(method_frame, header_frame, body)
            self.channel.basic_ack(method_frame.delivery_tag)
            return method_frame, header_frame, body
        else:
            print('No message returned')

    def close(self):
        self.channel.close()
        self.connection.close()
```

#### Calling Consumer:

```py
# Create Basic Message Receiver which creates a connection
# and channel for consuming messages.
basic_message_receiver = BasicMessageReceiver(
    credentials["broker_id"],
    credentials["username"],
    credentials['password'],
    credentials['region']
)

# Consume the message that was sent.
basic_message_receiver.get_message("q_name")

# Close connections.
basic_message_receiver.close()
```

I hope the above helps.
Thanks