# system error: 10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host in python

Tags: python, sql, database, error-handling, connection

I have a very simple code to connect to the database in python.

```
import mysql.connector

connector = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="testuser", 
password="testuser", database='testdb',port='1433')

print(connector)

cur = connector.cursor()

print(cur)
```

The above code is giving me below error:

> mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:1433', system error: 10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

I didn't get proper answer in any related question. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: you can look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814802/python-errno-10054-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-h). Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Unfortunately reconnecting didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I got to know that this issue occurred when i was using MySQL connector for Microsoft SQL Database. I have to use pyodbc to connect to SQL database.