# How to handle urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host>?

Tags: python, urllib

I have following small piece of python script:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def download_file(url):
    fp = open(url.split("=")[-1] + ".pdf", 'wb')
    req = urlopen(url)
    CHUNK = 20480
    chunk = req.read(CHUNK)
    fp.write(chunk)
    fp.close()

for i in range(1, 10000, 1):
    download_file("__some__url__" + str(i))

print("Done.")
```

I keep this script running but after sometime(let's say after downloading 100 files) due to some reason it gives an error: `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host>`

How can I modify my code to handle that error i.e it shouldn't stop script and handle i.e wait for connection to restore and then resume downloading where it left?

PS: I know it only downloads 20KB from URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For possible causes for this error, you could have a look at [python: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8814802/3545273). My conclusion after reading the highest vote answers is just that it can happen and your code should be prepared to it.

I would use a `try: ... except ...` block in a loop here and and add a increasing delay before retrying a failed connection:

```
def download_file(url):
    # prefere with when exceptions are expected
    with open(url.split("=")[-1] + ".pdf", 'wb') as fp:
        delay = 5
        max_retries = 3
        for _ in range(max_retries):
            try:
                req = urlopen(url)
                CHUNK = 20480
                chunk = req.read(CHUNK)
                fp.write(chunk)
                break                # do not loop after a successfull download...
            except urllib.error.URLError:
                time.sleep(delay)
                delay *= 2
        else:                # signal an abort if download was not possible
            print(f"Failed for {url} after {max_retries} attempt")
            # or if you want to abort the script
            # raise Exception(f"Failed for {url} after {max_retries} attempt")
```