# Getting 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host' error message

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

[image]

[image]

I have been building a practice website for over a year and have never encountered this problem. I have not knowingly made any adjustments to my firewalls and internet settings.

Today I tried to run a few different versions of my website (from between a few days and few months old) and I encountered the same issue on all of them. So I was able to rule out a rogue piece of code in a recent version causing the problem.

I restarted my PC, cleared my cache on Google Chrome and also tested the issue on Firefox.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I am scratching my head to what triggered this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582036/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host) or more closely related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814802/python-errno-10054-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-h

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2**

After solving the issues I raised in Update 1 using this [tutorial](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/youll-need-a-new-app-to-open-this-windowsdefender/8ff047c7-e21c-4d6a-8db0-4bf5207767ec), the problem still persisted. Maybe everything I said in Update 1 was entirely wrong or maybe Update 1 and 2 complimented each other.

It now seems that I have managed to permanently fix the problem by removing these lines of code - `request.META.get("REMOTE_ADDR")` and `requests.get('http://ip.42.pl/raw').text`. Many months ago these two lines of code served a purpose and caused no issue. I don't know why these two lines of code started causing an issue. But thankfully I no longer needed them, so it was safe to delete them.

**Update 1**

It turns out the original solution I proposed was wrong. I realised my problem was to do with Windows Security. I can only assume that one of the default Microsoft updates impacted the Windows Security.

Something happened which meant that 'Run quick scan' and 'View security dashboard' did not work any more.

[image]

I was getting the 'open this windowsdefender link'.

[image]

As a temporary fix I have discovered that sometimes just clicking 'Ok' on the error message resolves the issue. But I am actively trying to find a thorough, proper solution to the problem.

**Original Comment**

I have a Django Projects folder where I keep the latest version of my website and backups of my website from previous days, weeks, months and years. This folder had ballooned in size to 13.9GB and it contained 310,165 Files.

This was causing the problem. So I had to create a Django Projects Recent folder and a Django Projects Old folder.

Comment: Just out of curiosity is the backup you talk about backups of your code? If so are you using any [version control](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control) system?

Comment: My current back up method is haphazard and I need to look into getting a proper version control system.