# ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-requests

## I am successfully able to send an HTTP GET request using Python 3.9. However, when attempting the same request using Django 4.2 and Python 3.10, it fails to work as expected.

```
import requests
headersa = {
            'accept': 'text/plain',
            'x-api-key': 'pgH7QzFHJx4w46fI~5Uzi4RvtTwlEXp'
            }
url = "https://10.11.11.66:1003/config/v6/servers"
try:
    response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headersa, verify=False, timeout=50)
    print(response.text)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e)
```

When I use Python 3.9, I am able to send an HTTP GET request without any issues, and it functions correctly. However, when I attempt to send the same HTTP GET request within the context of a Django 4.2 project using Python 3.10, I encounter errors or unexpected behavior.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814802/python-errno-10054-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-h

Comment: Thanks, @Jisson for your response, I have tried all those.  In python 3.9 it is working properly. Python 3.10 environment only fac facing this issue.                          
File "D:\venv_fr_pych\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 501, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

Comment: check the other possibility of verify=False

Comment: try with httpx, https://pypi.org/project/httpx/

Comment: https://www.python-httpx.org/