# Inconsistent browser retry behaviour for timed out POST requests

Tags: node.js, http, google-chrome

I am experiencing occasional retries for a POST request, when there is no response from server due to timeout. All modern browsers have retry logic for idempotent requests (GET, HEAD, etc) but I am unable to reason out why it happens for a POST request.

I am testing this case using a simple node.js server with 3 routes and chrome browser .

```
/       : gives a html page with jquery and code snippets to fire ajax requests
/hi     : gives a text response 'hello'
/sleep  : request will timeout without any response
```

By default, node.js http server times out a request after 2 minutes.

### retry.js

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer();

server.on('request', function(req, res) {
    console.log(new Date() + ' ' + req.method + ' request on ' + req.url);

    if (req.url === '/sleep') {
        console.log('!!! sleeping');
    } else if (req.url === '/') {
        html = "$.post('/hi', {'for':'server'}, function() { console.log(arguments) } ).error(function() { console.log(arguments) })";
        html += "<br><br>";
        html += "$.post('/sleep', {'for':'infinite'}, function() { console.log(arguments) } ).error(function() { console.log(arguments) })";
        html += '<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>';
    
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end(html);
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('hello');
    }
});

server.listen(2020);
console.log('server listening on port 2020');
```

### run it

```
$ node retry.js 
server listening on port 2020
```

### 1

```
Load this page in browser http://localhost:2020

Fri Mar 01 2013 12:21:59 GMT+0530 (IST) GET request on /
Fri Mar 01 2013 12:21:59 GMT+0530 (IST) GET request on /favicon.ico
```

### 2

From Dev console, fire an ajax POST request to /hi using jquery

```
$.post('/hi', {'for':'server'}, function() { console.log(arguments) } ).error(function() { console.log(arguments) })
```

> Fri Mar 01 2013 12:22:05 GMT+0530 (IST) POST request on /hi

### 3

Fire a POST request to /sleep, results in a retry after 2 mins and errors out after 4 mins.

```
$.post('/sleep', {'for':'infinite'}, function() { console.log(arguments) } ).error(function() { console.log(arguments) })
```

server logs shows 2 requests

```
Fri Mar 01 2013 12:22:21 GMT+0530 (IST) POST request on /sleep
!!! sleeping
Fri Mar 01 2013 12:24:21 GMT+0530 (IST) POST request on /sleep
!!! sleeping
```

Firing it again, errors out in 2 mins without any retry.

```
Fri Mar 01 2013 12:30:01 GMT+0530 (IST) POST request on /sleep
!!! sleeping ?
```

#### It's not getting retried until we fire a request to /hi (or any other url) that results in a response. And retry happens for just one subsequent request to /sleep.

### In browser, the network tab shows the pattern like

```
/hi - success 
/sleep - cancelled - 4 mins (retry happens)
/sleep - cancelled - 2 mins (no retry)
/sleep - cancelled - 2 mins (no retry)
/hi - success 
/sleep - cancelled - 4 mins (retry happens)
/sleep - cancelled - 2 mins (no retry)
/sleep - cancelled - 2 mins (no retry)
```

---

### Question

Though we need to design our web app to tolerate these extra requests (either by browsers or any other intermediaries), this inconsistent browser retries looks weird. I had observed this behaviour in chrome (v16 & v24) & firefox.

Can someone help me to understand the browser retry logic behind timed out non-idempotent requests ?

#### Other relevant stackoverflow questions

[What happens when no response is received for a request? I'm seeing retries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302512/what-happens-when-no-response-is-received-for-a-request-im-seeing-retries)

Comment: Could this be a jquery problem ?

Comment: @Floby I had tried with jquery, prototype, plain html form for POST requests and just using browser bar to make GET requests. This behaviour remains same. It happens with both firefox & chrome.

Comment: Also to rule out node.js, I had tried with command line clients like curl & w3m. requests gets timed out in 2 mins as expected and no further retries. NODE_DEBUG=http,net node retry.js  clearly shows the new connection getting established upon a retry.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Browsers retry requests (including POSTs) when the connection is closed before receiving a response from the server.  This is defined in the [HTTP 1.1 Spec Section 8.2.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.4).

Comment: This answers the scenario. And we made our app resilient to intermediary retries. Thank you.

Comment: And what can close a connection before receiving a response? I have a process that last about 10 minutes. Testing here, in my machine, it works fine. But in another machine (both with windows/chrome), a POST retry is triggered after 2 or 3 minutes. I dont have any idea about what is happening. I can only think about browser timeout, but why it doesn't happen in my machine?

Comment: @robsonrosa A reverse proxy or a web application firewall in between the client and the server could potentially close the connection depending on how it is configured.