# Join two strings to form a file name in TCL

Tags: list, join, tcl

I cant get this to work .

```
set dut xyz
set fname [join {$dut "-CE"} ""]
```

But This works :

```
set fname [join {xyz "-CE"} ""]
```

I want fname as "xyz-CE"

Comment: What's wrong with `set fname "$dut-CE"`? Please *edit the question* so the answer would be obvious from it.

Comment: maybe you want append? `$ tcl
tcl>set s1 "qwe"
tcl>puts $s1
qwe
tcl>append s1 "123"
qwe123
tcl>puts $s1
qwe123
tcl>`

Comment: `{$dut "-CE"}` fails because you're using braces which inhibit variable substitution -- see http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following

```
set dut xyz
set fname ${dut}-CE
```

Normal word concatenation doesn't need a `join`.

Answer (score 0):

AS glenn said braces does not support variable substitution so group it with double quotes 
like this

```
set dut xyz
set fname [join "$dut -CE" ""]
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
set dut xyz
eval set fname [join {$dut "-CE"} ""]
```

it gives

```
xyz-CE
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can frame this as joining a list, there are simpler ways to do it if you treat it as a concatenation. In the spirit of "there's more than one way to do it"...

Simple variable substitution will work for the variable names you've used here (the parsing rules for `$` mean that it will stop at the `-` character):

```
set dut xyz
set fname "$dut-CE"
```

You don't even need the quotation marks (in Tcl, [everything is a string](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/everything+is+a+string)):

```
set dut xyz
set fname $dut-CE
```

You could use braces to delimit the variable name explicitly:

```
set dut xyz
set fname ${dut}-CE
```

You could also use an explicit subcommand for retrieving the value of `dut` ([`set`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.html) with one argument returns the value of that variable):

```
set dut xyz
set fname [set dut]-CE
```

Provided `fname` is not set or contains the empty string, you could use [`append`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/append.html) (but note that the `append` operation would be non-[idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077412/what-is-an-idempotent-operation): subsequent calls would keep appending to the existing value of `fname`):

```
set dut xyz
append fname $dut -CE
```

If you really wanted to do it using [`join`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.html) (converting a list into a string), create the list using the [`list`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.html) command so that `$dut` gets evaluated (braces prevent variable substitution). We specify the empty string `""` as the `join` separator, as the default is a space.

```
set dut xyz
set fname [join [list $dut -CE] ""]
```

Lastly, while there is a [`concat`](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/concat) command, that returns a list (with the elements separated by spaces, which is not what you want).