# Packing a node bash CLI for execution from the /usr/local/bin/ folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, command-line-interface

Does anyone know how to achieve being to execute a node bash proram from the command line, for example the way you might call "brew install" - normally, you need to call "node **NAME_OF_CLI**".

The problem is that I can't just throw my program into the /bin folder because I would need to put the node_modules folder in there as well - and that just does not seem acceptable. Is there a known way to package all of these things together so it will be an executable program?

Also, I do not want this to be in npm - this is not a public module.

Comment: Additionally, I do not have want to have to implicitly call "node" - so I have it my path. This seems to work, but I just want to be clear that I am looking for a solution that does not include invoking node manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do.

## Distribute your program in a traditional archive

- package your program into a distributable archive such as .tar.bz2 (preferred), .tar.gz, or .zip (if it needs to support windows)
- In the archive include node itself, your fully-populated node_modules folder, and all your other javascript modules, files, whatnot
- Because node is platform-dependent, you will thus need a different archive distribution for each target architecture (linux/windows/osx)
- These above are consistent with the [12 Factor App](http://www.12factor.net/build-release-run) Build/Release/Run principles.
- Include an executable shell script that is your program's entry point that can do something like

## Include an executable shell script wrapper

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=$(dirname "${0}")
exec "${DIR}/node/bin/node" "${DIR}/main.js" "${@}"
```

## Install via curl command line copy/paste

I noticed in the comments you want a homebrew-style install-via curl command line. In that case, all of the above still applies but your curl command downloads a shell script that does:

- download the distribution archive
- extract it in place (`/usr/local/programname` would be reasonable)
- If necessary, set up symlinks or copy files into a `bin` directory in the user's PATH (`/usr/local/bin/programname` would be reasonable)

So your curl command might be `curl http://example.com/myprogram/install.sh | sh`

Again, this is consistent with the [12 Factor App](http://www.12factor.net/build-release-run) principles, which are sound. In particular:

- Do not expect the target user to already have node installed
- Do not expect the target user to install node by following your directions
- Do not bother trying to support varying versions of node unless you really have a requirement to do so
- It is OK to bundle node with your app. It makes it easier to install, easier to support, and less prone to errors.

## Misc Tips

- Make sure your installer code is [idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077412/what-is-an-idempotent-operation)
- You may want to explicitly set the wrapper shell script executable on the target machine with `chmod` in the `install.sh` script as zip archives and tar under some circumstances won't preserve that
- Watch out for OS X's crappy old `tar`. Use `gnutar` instead.

## Reference material

Refer to homebrew's `go` ruby program for ideas/inspiration https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go

Here are some examples taken from build script in [the github repo for my web site](https://github.com/focusaurus/peterlyons.com/blob/v4.5.0/bin/tasks.sh#L439)

```
install_node() {
  local VERSION=${1-0.10.7}
  local PREFIX=${2-node}
  local PLATFORM=$(uname | tr A-Z a-z)
  case $(uname -p) in
      i686)
          ARCH=x86
      ;;
  esac
  mkdir -p "${PREFIX}"
  curl --silent \
    "http://nodejs.org/dist/v${VERSION}/node-v${VERSION}-${PLATFORM}-${ARCH}.tar.gz" \
    | tar xzf - --strip-components=1 -C "${PREFIX}"
}


task:dist() {
  cd "${CODE_PATH}"
  local GIT_REF="${1-master}"
  local BUILD_DIR="build"
  local DIST_DIR="dist"
  local PREFIX="${SITE}-${GIT_REF}"
  dirs "${BUILD_DIR}" "${DIST_DIR}"
  echo doing git archive
  git archive --format=tar --prefix="${PREFIX}/" "${GIT_REF}" | \
    #extract that archive into a temporary build directory
    "${TAR}" --directory "${BUILD_DIR}" --extract
  #install node
  NODE_VERSION=$(./bin/jsonpath.coffee engines.node)
  echo installing node
  install_node "${NODE_VERSION}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${PREFIX}/node"
  #Note we use npm from the build platform (OS X) here instead of
  #the one for the run platform as they are incompatible
  echo install npm packages
  (cd "${BUILD_DIR}/${PREFIX}" && npm install --silent --production)
  echo creating archive
  "${TAR}" --directory "${BUILD_DIR}" --create --bzip2 --file "${DIST_DIR}/${PREFIX}.tar.bz2" .
}
```

Comment: Indeed! Thanks a ton. I might actually use the npm link option just so the repo can be live and users can continue to pull the updated program, which will automagically be symlinked. But I certainly do like to know that my original idea is possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a file to the ./bin folder

```
$ cd myproject
$ mkdir bin
```

bin/my_bin_file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
require('../main_file.js');
```

Add a "bin" option to your package.json:

```
"bin": {
    "my_bin_file": "./bin/my_bin_file"
}
```

Make it executable

```
$ chmod +x bin/my_bin_file
```

Install globally:

```
npm install -g
```

EDIT: npm can install your package globally to the system without it being public, and there is a shebang in the bin file that tells the system how to invoke it (no need to call node on the cli explicitly)

Comment: Ahh... I tried with "npm link" but it made a symlink to the repo. Both of these solutions aren't any good because I do not want to have the user do any of these things. I want them to be able to curl my program into their /bin directory and start using it right away.

Comment: Do everything except "npm install -g". Then you can write a small shell script that just downloads your package and runs npm install -g. As far as I'm aware, there isn't another way to package them single-binary style.

Everything except 'npm install -g' is a one-time thing on your end.