# Is a singleton constructor idempotent?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm still trying to grasp both concepts, so if I'm misunderstanding something kindly explain.

I've read a few sources on idempotent operations (namely the [SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077412/what-is-an-idempotent-operation)) and yesterday a senior dev at my workplace sent this [article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) around about singleton's. While reading the singleton article I was wondering, is a constructor for an object that properly implements the singleton pattern idempotent?

My understanding is that it would be because calling `Singleton.Instance()` (v. 6 from the Singleton article) more than 1 time would not change anything because a singleton cannot be instantiated more than once, but I'm not entirely sure if I'm combining the two topics correctly.

Comment: Yes, it is. Calling the constructor a second (or third, etc.) time does not change any state. So it's idempotent.

Comment: I'd like my avatar picture back, please. Was here first :)

Comment: Jim, thanks! Dialecticus, It's a great picture, what can I say? haha

Comment: Note that programmers use "idempotent" differently from how mathematicians use it.  For mathematicians, a function `foo` is said to be an *idempotent function* if for all `x` the value `foo(x)` is a *fixed point* of `foo`.  That is, `foo(foo(x))` is always equal to `foo(x)`. Programmers use idempotent to mean "there is no difference between calling a function once and calling the function two, three, four.. times", which is different.  For example, in the mathematician sense, `abs` is idempotent because `abs(abs(x))` equals `abs(x)` for all `x`.

Comment: And yes, a singleton factory is a good example of an idempotent operation, in the programmer sense.  It is not an example of an idempotent operation in the mathematician sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an operation is described as idempotent then what that really means is any calls made to it with the **same parameters** should result in no additional state change. For example, in a REST API a `DELETE` request is generally idempotent which means if I make subsequent requests to delete a resource and it's already gone I would still get a success back. So from the users point of view it *appears* like something has happened, but really the system isn't changing anything it's simply acknowledging the request i.e.

```
User: "Please delete resource A"

System: "Check status of resource A"

System: "Resource A found, deleting Resource A" || "Resource A not found"

System: "Return OK"
```

So taking that into the concept of a singleton it works pretty much the same. You make subsequent requests to *create* an object, however, the operation is only performed once - the rest are simply returned the created instance.

Comment: gotcha. I forgot idempotent functions must have the same parameters, so I guess a singleton constructor could be idempotent but doesn't have to be (depending on if it accepts parameters or not)