# Is there any way to send SMS using Twilio at a Later time

Tags: java, sms, twilio, sms-gateway

I am using Twilio to send SMS in my web app.It works perfectly and sms is delivered within 15 seconds.i wanted to send SMS at a later time.For example Suppose a meeting is fixed on 1st dec 12 noon.So to inform the client i can send sms saying meeting at so and so date time.Now just before the scheduled time,automatically client will get a SMS as a reminder.Is there any way to do so.I am looking for a method in [twilio API](http://twilio.github.io/twilio-java/) but could not find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What fruityp said is just right. You should write your own program that runs every X minutes (using cron on Unix based systems or the task scheduler on windows) or a service (with a timer) that checks if an SMS should be sent through twilio.

If you take the program that runs every X minutes route, you need to make it [idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077412/what-is-an-idempotent-operation) so that you don't end up sending multiple SMS when you want to send just one. This looks obvious, but it may become an issue if your program takes Y minutes, where Y > X (you may end up having two instances running at the same time). On the task scheduler (on windows) you can explicitly set it up so that a new instance isn't launched until the previous one ends running.

Answer (score 2):

This is not something Twilio supports, you will have to program this yourself to check if any SMS's need to be sent out ~ say every 5 minutes. I don't know if you're building a web / desktop application but this applies to both.