# Why multiple openings/closing with a same kernel does not have effect?

Tags: image-processing, mathematical-morphology

I know about closing and opening, but there is still one question to me! According to the "Digital Image Processing, 3rd edition", by Gonzales, The multiple application of opening/closing doesn't have any effect after the first time you apply it! I couldn't figure it out? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behavior since openings and closings are [idempotent operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). An operation is idempotent if, whenever it is applied twice to any value, it gives the same result as if it were applied once: f(f(x)) = f(x).
Openings are operators on lattice L that are idempotent, increasing, and anti-extensive while closings are operators on L that are idempotent, increasing, and extensive. One can find a discussion on what is idempotence [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077412/what-is-an-idempotent-operation).

In a more intuitive sense, an opening on set X is a erosion followed by dilation by the same structuring function. Once the first iteration is done the set X does not change since the erosion and dilation remove and add the same '1's in the set X. The product of opening and closing is also an idempotent operation - which is very interesting. One the other hand if at each iteration one changes the radius of the structuring element for the openings/closings, one would obtain an Alternated Sequential Filter, which produces multiscale simplification of the image, thus producing a [scale-space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_space).

I would refer you to the book by Jean Serra on mathematical morphology or better understanding.