# Iterations in morphology closing

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-morphology

I have a code that goes like:

```
def blockKernel(sizeX, sizeY = None):
    if sizeY == None:
        sizeY = sizeX
    return np.ones((sizeX, sizeY), np.uint8)

img = readImage() // skipping readImage function, since irrelevant
closeBlock1 = cv.morphologyEx(img, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, blockKernel(3), iterations=1) 
closeBlock2 = cv.morphologyEx(img, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, blockKernel(3), iterations=3)
```

I get the following outputs:

closeBlock1:

[image: closeBlock1]

closeBlock2:

[image: closeBlock2]

But then I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062572/why-multiple-openings-closing-with-a-same-kernel-does-not-have-effect). It says:

> According to the "Digital Image Processing, 3rd edition", by Gonzales,
>   The multiple application of opening/closing doesn't have any effect
>   after the first time you apply it!

But that's not the result I'm getting. I'm getting 1 vs 3 iterations, and getting different results. Am I doing something wrong or misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cv.morphologyEx(img, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, blockKernel(3), iterations=3)` applies the closing with the iteration of kernel, it does not iterate the closing.

The morphological closing is a dilation followed by an erosion. This function applies the dilation by iterating the 3x3 dilation three times, then the erosion by again iterating the 3x3 erosion three times.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, let `d` = dilation and `e` = erosion. So closing = `e(d(img))` but `iterations=3` does `e(e(e(d(d(d(img))))))`?

Comment: Great, got it. Thank you :)