# AngularJs: loop through number

Tags: angularjs

I'm looping a number (from 0 to 7) to get the index of the next day.
Here bellow is a fiddle working.

The problem is the first day is not "Monday", but Friday. So, the number is not 0 but 4...

I do not understand where is the problem.
Please help

```js
(function(){
 
 var app = angular.module('myApp', [ ]);

 app.controller('CalenderController', function(){
  this.firstDay = -1;
        
        this.getDayName = function(){
   this.firstDay++;
   if(this.firstDay ==  7){
    this.firstDay = 0;
   }
   return dayNames[this.firstDay];
  };
        
        this.dayLength = function(){
            return new Array(13);
        }
 });

 //Variables 
 var dayNames = ['Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'So'];

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="CalenderController as calender">
     <div ng-repeat="item in calender.dayLength() track by $index">
         {{calender.getDayName()}}
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times; The answer to the last question you asked on the same topic gave almost identical answers to this.

Comment: I had to repost a easier way to explain the problem. Previous question will be deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very bad idea to leave side-effects in functions that are being watched by Angular. Any function that is called from within an expression `{{something()}}` will be evaluated on every digest cycle, and so, these functions must be [idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077412/what-is-an-idempotent-operation).

The `getDayName` function is not idempotent, because it changes `this.firstDay`.

Not only that, but it also returns a different value every time it's called, and so it causes the digest cycle to re-run (until it's aborted by Angular after 10 iterations).

Instead, use the `$index` directly to access the `dayName` array:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in calendar.dayLength()">
  {{calendar.dayNames[$index % 7]}}
</div>
```

and expose `dayNames` as a VM with `this.dayNames`.

**EDIT:** On second thought, it's better to expose this as a function, so that you could do mod 7 there:

```
$scope.getDayName = function(dayIndex){
   return dayNames[dayIndex % 7];
}
```

and in the View:

```
{{calendar.getDayName($index)}}
```

**EDIT 2:** If you don't need to have a flat DOM hierarchy of `<div>`s for all the days over 2 weeks, you could even do this much simpler:

```
<div ng-repeat="week in [0, 1]">
  <div ng-repeat="day in dayNames">
    {{day}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is a perfect explanation. `[ ]` should be `( )` no? I made a jsFiddle with the `( )`: https://jsfiddle.net/07osg7ae/1/

Comment: @gr3g, `[]` if you are referencing an array directly; `()` if you are exposing it as a function. If you are using a function, then I suggest that you use `index % 7` within the function, rather than in the View - it's a better separation of concerns.

Comment: You are totaly right, I do not even need a function

Comment: @gr3g, you don't need it, but then it forces you to add logic of `$index % 7` to the view, which is not very clean

Comment: Oh, just read your update. Making operation in the function is better?

Comment: @gr3g, function is better to hide away some logic from the View. See another update

Comment: In fact I need it to repeat the number of days that are defined in the month. (Can be 28 sometimes). This value is  reached in the ng-repeat.

Comment: @gr3g, ok, well... then a function is a way to go.