# HTTP idempotent and non-idempotent methods?

Tags: http

what are the HTTP idempotent and non-idempotent methods available as per RFC7231 by group?

methods:

```
GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD, DELETE, TRACE, CONNECT
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an idempotent operation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077412/what-is-an-idempotent-operation)

Comment: @kryger it is not duplicate. I did not explain what is an idempotent operation. If you check, my answer so precise for a simple question. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Idempotent http methods:

```
GET, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD, DELETE, TRACE
```

Non-Idempotent http methods:

```
POST, CONNECT
```

Reference:
[Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Semantics and Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-8.1.3)

Comment: In addition to the idempotent and non-idempotent HTTP verbs which have already been covered. I want to clarify that it is extremely important to note that these VERBS are not inherently idempotent or non-idempotent. Making them behave in a way that honors the spec and/or RESTful architecture practices is a side-effect of the user code. So please if you are making an API be aware to design in a way that honors the idempotency of the target VERB. And likewise if working with a third party API. Don't take for granted that hey may have "did it wrong".