# Is directory resource idempotent

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

> Please help me understand if a directory resource idempotent??

I don't find a complete explanation regarding this on Chef Docs except the following information:
:create Default. Create a directory. If a directory already exists (but does not match), update that directory to match.

Source: https://docs.chef.io/resource_directory.html

Answer (score 3):

Idempotent simply means "has no additional effect if it is called more than once with the same input parameters" ([What is an idempotent operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077412/what-is-an-idempotent-operation))

If you run a recipe containing a directory resource twice, the 2nd run should have no effect on the directory. For instance the first run of:

```
directory "#{node.default['jboss']['root']}" do
  owner 'jboss'
  group 'jboss'
  mode '0755'
  action :create
end
```

will create the directory, if it does not exist, and make sure its owner and group are set to jboss and that permissions on it are '0755'. A second run would do nothing (unless you'd changed any of those things, in which case it would bring it back to that state)

Answer (score 1):

Chef's action names are a bit of a misnomer. The `:create` action actually means "idempotently ensure that this directory exists and has the given owner/group/mode if provided". It won't actually create it unless needed.