# How does FoundationDB handle conflicting transactions?

Tags: java, cap, foundationdb

I'm curious how does FoundationDB handle a situation in which there are multiple transactions trying to update the same key?

If one client executes this transaction:

```
db.run((Transaction tr) -> {
  tr.set(Tuple.from("key").pack(), Tuple.from("valueA").pack());
  return null;
});
```

While another client executes a conflicting transaction:

```
db.run((Transaction tr) -> {
  tr.set(Tuple.from("key").pack(), Tuple.from("valueB").pack());
  return null;
});
```

What will happen inside FoundationDB to resolve that conflict?

Comment: What does the documentation say will happen?

Comment: I couldn't find anything describing this situation in the docs, though I could've missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I've been exploring and testing FoundationDB (I guess everyone is playing with it at the moment) and as a part of my explorations I've made some simple tests. One of them should answer your questions:

So, below is an example (hope you wouldn't mind Scala):

```
import com.apple.foundationdb._
import com.apple.foundationdb.tuple._
import resource.managed

import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.util.Random

object Example {

  val THREAD_COUNT = 1

  @volatile var v0: Long = 0
  @volatile var v1: Long = 0
  @volatile var v2: Long = 0
  @volatile var v3: Long = 0
  @volatile var v4: Long = 0

  def doJob(db: Database, x: Int): Unit = {
    db.run((tr) => {
      val key = Tuple.from("OBJ", Long.box(100)).pack()

      val current = Tuple.fromBytes(tr.get(key).join())
      if (Random.nextInt(100) < 2) {
        out(current)
      }

      val next = mutable.ArrayBuffer(current.getLong(0), current.getLong(1), current.getLong(2), current.getLong(3), current.getLong(4))

      if (x == 1 && v1 == next(1)) { println(s"again: $v1, v0=$v0, 0=${next(0)}")}
      if (x == 0 && v0 > next(0)) { out(current); ??? } else { v0 = next(0)}
      if (x == 1 && v1 > next(1)) { out(current); ??? } else { v1 = next(1)}
      if (x == 2 && v2 > next(2)) { out(current); ??? } else { v2 = next(2)}
      if (x == 3 && v3 > next(3)) { out(current); ??? } else { v3 = next(3)}
      if (x == 4 && v4 > next(4)) { out(current); ??? } else { v4 = next(4)}

      next.update(x, next(x) + 1)
      val nv = Tuple.from(next.map(v => Long.box(v)) :_*)

      tr.set(key, nv.pack())
    })

  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    if (THREAD_COUNT > 5) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("")
    }

    val fdb: FDB = FDB.selectAPIVersion(510)
    for (db <- managed(fdb.open())) {
      // Run an operation on the database
      db.run((tr) => {
        for (x <- 0 to 10000) {
          val k = Tuple.from(s"OBJ", x.toLong.underlying()).pack()
          val v = Tuple.from(Long.box(0), Long.box(0), Long.box(0), Long.box(0), Long.box(0)).pack()
          tr.set(k, v)
          null
        }
      })


      val threads = (0 to THREAD_COUNT).map { x =>
        new Thread(new Runnable {
          override def run(): Unit = {
            while (true) {
              try {
                doJob(db, x)
              } catch {
                case t: Throwable =>
                  t.printStackTrace()
              }
            }
          }
        })
      }

      threads.foreach(_.start())
      threads.foreach(_.join())


    }
  }

  private def out(current: Tuple) = {
    println("===")
    println((v0, v1, v2, v3, v4))
    println((Thread.currentThread().getId, current))
  }
}
```

So, this thing allows you to start several threads writing into the same object.
There is some unirequired code left from other experiments, ignore it (or use for your own experiments).

This code spawns your threads, then each thread reads a tuple of five longs, like `(0,1,0,0,0)` from key `("OBJ", 100)`, then increments
value corresponding to thread number then writes it back and increments one of the volatile counters.

And these are my observations:

1. When you run this example configured with one thread you will see that it writes very quick,
2. When you increase concurrency you will notice that your writes are slowing down (expected)...
3. ...And you will see that this code is being executed from time to time: `println(s"again: $v1, v0=$v0, 0=${next(0)}")`

So, essentially, when a conflict occurs FoundationDB clients are trying to commit the transactions until they succeed. You may find more details in [this chapter](https://apple.github.io/foundationdb/developer-guide.html#transactions-with-unknown-results) of the docs. Then look at the [architecture overview diagram.](https://apple.github.io/foundationdb/architecture.html)

Also note that your transactions are just functions. Hopefully - [idempotent functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077412/what-is-an-idempotent-operation).

And you should know that in many cases you may avoid conflicts by using [atomic operations](https://apple.github.io/foundationdb/developer-guide.html#atomic-operations) on your value.

Hope this answers your question.

I would advice you to read all the [official docs](https://apple.github.io/foundationdb/contents.html) through so you may find many
intersting things there including how the database developers [consider CAP theorem](https://apple.github.io/foundationdb/cap-theorem.html), nice examples of [cool distributed data structures](https://apple.github.io/foundationdb/design-recipes.html) and many other technical details and interesting things.

Comment: > And you will see that this code is being executed from time to time: println(s"again: $v1, v0=$v0, 0=${next(0)}")

What does that mean here? Sorry, the code is hard to follow.

Comment: Effectively it means that the increment code has been executed twice for the same value within the tuple. This means that the client re-executes transactions in case of failures.