# Should a functions return value be assigned to a variable or used directly?

Tags: python

I am writing a function to calculate the distance of an object using a HCSR04 sensor. The sensor sends out a sound and waits for the return. Using the time it takes for the sound to return, I can calculate the distance of the object. My function performs this task and returns the distance in centimeters. I use the returned value to judge if my robot can continue moving forwards and in which direction to turn when an object is blocking its path.

I use the function as follows:

```
def sides():
    if sen.dist_1() + sen.dist_5() < stg.safe_front_dist:
        print("Sides Checked - Going back.")
        return "back"

    elif sen.dist_1() > sen.dist_5():
        print("Sides Checked - Left.")
        return "left"

    elif sen.dist_1() < sen.dist_5():
        print("Sides Checked - Right.")
        return "right"

    else:
        print("Error checking sides.")
        return "error"
```

While this works without problems, I am wondering if it is better to assign the values of each function to a variable then compare the variables. This would look like:

```
def sides():
    dist_1 = sen.dist_1()
    dist_5 = sen.dist_5()

    if dist_1 + dist_5 < stg.safe_front_dist:
        print("Sides Checked - Going back.")
        return "back"

    elif dist_1 > dist_5:
        print("Sides Checked - Left.")
        return "left"

    elif dist_1 < dist_5:
        print("Sides Checked - Right.")
        return "right"

    else:
        print("Error checking sides.")
        return "error"
```

Comment: In *this specific case*, there are significant efficiency gains to only calling your function once. In *the general case*, this is a question that doesn't have a canonical answer, and is generally a matter of opinion -- which we try to stay out of on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am wondering if it is better to assign the values of each function to a variable then compare the variables.

It depends on the case, really. In your case, since you're calling the function *many* times, you could save resources by only calling the function once and assigning the return value to a variable. That way, you avoid having to repeatedly call the function and recalculate it's return value.

Comment: That does make sense. So if I were to only call the functions once then assigning the returned value to a variable would not be any more effecient. Correct?

Comment: Exactly. Calling a function multiple times wastes resources. Call the function, once, and the store it's value for later use.

Comment: ... although it does depend on the function.  This can be done if the function is *idempotent*, that is, it has no side effects when called and always gives the same result for a given input.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077412/what-is-an-idempotent-operation?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa