# Count lines with integers in them using bash and wc -l

Tags: bash, shell, grep, wc

A utility on my Linux machine outputs a log to 'stdout'.
In each line, there is either a String or an Integer, it looks like the following:

```
[ERROR] resource busy, retrying
0989282882
[DEBUG] starting process with pid 4028
7918361566
1037491392
[DEBUG] starting process with pid 4056
2873187983
7853738301
1290312037
[DEBUG] done with init
1872989829
[DEBUG] cleaning up
8917982882
```

(In reality it is way longer)

I want to count the lines that have integers in them.

I already used: `program | grep DEBUG | wc -l` to get the debug count (same for `ERROR`)

But how can I count the integers? They don't have anything static like the strings, that I could grep...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use grep after specifying a regular expression to identify integers.

For this particular case,
`grep -E "^[0-9]+" | wc -l` 
should work.

Here,

^ means the start of the line

[0-9] means any number from 0 to 9

+ means one or more such digits

Answer (score 1):

You do not need wc  for this, grep has `-c`

```
program |  grep -c -E -x '[[:digit:]]+'
```

- `-c` print only a count of selected lines
- `-E` extended regexp (you can omit it and use the pattern `[0-9]\+`)
- `-x` match the entire line not just part of it

See [POSIX grep manual](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)

Alternatively, since you mentioned also `[DEBUG]`, you can use `awk` for a single pass (especialy if your `program` is not [idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077412/what-is-an-idempotent-operation))

```
program | awk  '/^[0-9]+$/ { numbers++ } /^\[DEBUG\]/ {debugs++} END { print numbers,debugs }'
```

See [POSIX awk manual](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this `program  | grep -E "^[0-9]+" | wc -l`. This will match lines which start with 1 or more digits. Seems like enough for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
program | grep '^[0-9].*$' | wc -l
```