# Shortening redundant calculation

Tags: python, syntax

Is there a faster or shorter way of writing the following code to aviod calculating `f(x)` twice without defining another variable?

```
# could be any function or condition
if f(x) == 0:
    print(f(x))

# with additional variable
y = f(x)
if y == 0:
    print(y)
```

Comment: What's wrong with using the additional variable?

Comment: If you need this frequently, define a `print_if_0()` function.

Comment: @Barmar the condition is arbitrary, I am only concerned with shortening the syntax

Comment: Whatever the condition is, put it in a function.

Comment: @not_speshal I just want to know if there is a shorter way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The walrus operator would save you an extra line (but not the assignment of `y`).

```
if (y := f(x)) == 0:
    print(y)
```

Comment: This is not actually shorter if you put it all on one line, because the `():` are longer than the newline that's saved.

Comment: @Barmar But if you put it all in one line someone's gonna PEP8 you.

Comment: True, but the OP seems to be looking for a one-liner, and he also asked how to do it "without defining another variable". I'm not sure why he accepted this, since it doesn't seem to address either of his wishes.

Comment: @Barmar sometimes OPs don't know what they should actually want before they see it, eh.

Answer (score 0):

Define a `print_if_0()` function, and use that where you need it.

```
def print_if_0(n):
    if n == 0:
        print(n)

print_if_0(f(x))
```

You can generalize it to any test:

```
def print_if(f, val):
    if f(val):
        print(val)

print_if(lambda x: x == 0, f(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) to cache the results of `f(x)`.

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache
def f(x):
    ...
```

Comment: This will only work if the function is idempotent.

Comment: @Barmar do you mean "pure"? afaik "idempotent" means f(f(x)) = f(x).

Comment: @mkrieger1 That's the mathematical meaning. In CS, it means that invoking the same operation multiple times has the same result.

Comment: @mkrieger1 See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077412/what-is-an-idempotent-operation

Comment: @Barmar okay, thanks for the reminder. tbh I didn't quite understand what you meant. Nevermind.