# rails aborted "Don't know how to build task 'AdminUser.create!()"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I recently added the gem Active Admin to my rails applicaction (using rails 5.2.6), I got it to work with the default admin and it's working as intended. But I'm unable to add new admins with `AdminUser.create!(email: "admin@gmail.com", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password")` as I get the `rails aborted` error and then `Don't know how to build task 'AdminUser.create!(email: "admin@gmail.com", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password")`.

I already tried using `rails db:migrate` and running my seeds.
Also I am using the devise gem.

Full trace:

```
    rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'AdminUser.create!(email: example@gmail.com, password: password, password_confirmation: password)' (See the list of available tasks with `rails --tasks`)
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:59:in `[]'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:159:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/magus/Desktop/Proyecto ing software/grupo-56/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
/home/magus/Desktop/Proyecto ing software/grupo-56/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

As I said before, all the other ActiveAdmin functionalities are working as intended, it's just that I can't create new admins.

What am I doing wrong/could have forgotten to do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to add that admin into the database:

1. `rails console` - Just open the console and execute `AdminUser.create!(...)`.
2. `seeds.rb` - Open the `db/seeds.rb` file and paste `AdminUser.create!(...)`. Then run `rake db:seed`. Note that running `rake db:seed` multiple times will create that admin multiple times - it's best you have some sort of validations or use `AdminUser.find_or_create_by(...)` instead.
3. rake task - create a rake file in `lib/tasks`, name is not important but it should end in `.rake` (ex: `update.rake`)

```rb
task :add_admin do
  AdminUser.find_or_create_by(email: "admin@gmail.com", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password")
end
```

Run it with `rake add_admin`.

If you want that admin only for yourself, your local machine, use the console approach, otherwise pick the other two but make sure the rake tasks are [idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077412/what-is-an-idempotent-operation).

Comment: Thanks a ton! Second method worked with no issue! :)