# How to create an express update route with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I want to update an attribute within a JSON object using fetch PUT. I've created a put function taking in 2 URL parameters

```
app.put('/trustRoutes/:id/:item', (req, res){
```

I am able to update the data with a single parameter but since I only want to change one value inside that object, calling put will replace the whole object with my new body.

below is what I've tried.

```
app.put('/trustRoutes/:id/:item', (req, res) => {
    readFile(data => {
 
      const userId = req.params['id/item'];
      // have also tried const userId = req.params.id.item
      data[userId] = req.body;
  
//write data back to file
```

I looked around at other examples but couldn't find any that were updating data instead of GET. If there is one I missed please let me know.

Comment: `data[userId] = { ...data[userId], ...req.body };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PUT requests are great for completely overwriting a resource, and is idempotent. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077412/what-is-an-idempotent-operation) does a good job explaining idempotency. For updating a resource partially, a PATCH request is a better choice.

```
app.patch('/trustRoutes/:id/:item', (req, res) => {
    readFile(data => {
        data[userId] = req.params[id];
        data[item] = req.params[item];
        // A get request for this resource would now show both of the updated values
        // Write file
```