# Why set the "action" and "method" for a Form in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

In my javascript book, there is this code:

```
form.action="echo.pl"
form.method="POST"
```

The book describes these two lines of code as

> statements to specify a submission method and a server-side script to process the form.

But I have no idea what they are talking about. This code is part of a larger code that first assigns form values, then runs the server-side script response echo the submitted name=value pairs assigned by the script. Since there is no proper explanation, I am unable to understand what it means.

Comment: I am not sure if the question is about *HTML form/submission in general* or the *lines of code posted* ..

Comment: I suggest finding (e.g., via Google) a tutorial about how HTML forms work. If you're going to be looking at JS code that manipulates forms it's good to understand how forms work _without_ JS...

Answer (score 2):

A HTML form is a way of submitting user data to the server. But to submit data, there are a couple of questions:

- Which part of server (sort of) to submit to? (ie, which script/program will handle the submitted data). This is best represented by the URL to the resource.
- How should the data be submitted? There are various HTTP methods -- GET/POST/PUT/DELETE/ etc etc ..

The answer lies in the form tag's attribute:

```
<form method="<METHOD OF SUBMIT: GET/POST>" action="<WHERE TO SUBMIT?: URL OF SCRIPT" ..>
```

In your code, `form` is a reference to the form, and when you say:

- `form.action`: You modify the URL to submit to.
- `form.method`: You modify the HTTP method to use to submit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a page that will handle the form's data when the user submits it.
The form's `action` attribute is the page it will send data to using the method described in its `method` attribute. See this question for [difference between GET and POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them).

[From w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-FORM):

```
action      %URI;          #REQUIRED -- server-side form handler --
method      (GET|POST)     GET       -- HTTP method used to submit the form--
```