# is it possible to pass value using POST method via hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible to make a form submit POST style with an anchor?

```
<form>
    <input name="foo" />
    <input name="bar" />

    <a href="#">Submit this form</a>
</form>
```

---

*Original question, also gets explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19094534/2519416) by [Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2519416/martijn)*

Is it possible to pass a value using hyperlink as a `POST` method ??
i want to pass a value on clicking an image to the next page.

Comment: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) might be a good read.

Comment: You could do an Ajax call to override the link.

Comment: Clicking on a link that just has a reference to another URL will fire a `GET` request. If you want to make a post, you'll need to use Javascript to force a `POST` on the element's click event. Cross domain issues may happen if you're linking to another domain.

Comment: Whilst no code has been posted, this is not a stupid question if you're a newbie. One might well wonder, if you're new to all this, why this is possible only via a form or AJAX, rather than via a hyperlink.

Comment: was there any thing wrong :o

Comment: @Aayush I'm nominating this questions for reopening. So far you've got 2 votes out of a necessary 5 to reopen. Do read the closure message below to get a better idea of how to avoid having downvotes and closed questions. I almost agree with the guys that closed your question.

Comment: a form is obviously included.I thought people would understand ...my bad

Comment: I've editted your anwer to include a form so your question gets more obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im going to leave my original answer below, why an anchor can not perform a post call. However, the question has been rephrazed, this answer will answer that question:

You can not use a anchor to submit, but its somewhat common practice to make it trigger a submit:

```
$('a#myAnchor').click(function(){ $('#myForm').submit() })
/// Or an image, doesn't really matter for jQuery:
$('img#myImg').click(function(){ $('#myForm').submit() })
// Or native js:
document.getElementById('myImg').onclick = function(){ document.getElemetById('myForm').submit() });
```

if the element you want to trigger a submit with is inside of a form:

```
$('element').click(function(){ $(this).closest('form').submit() });
```

---

No. Anchors are GETbecause anchors send you to an url, which makes it GET, never POST.

POST is data being send in post-format, it gets encoding in a way the server can handle it (important for images and such)

In this other topic [this reply explains difference between GET and POST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/504993/2519416)

If you must, and I mean REALLY must, you could use jQuery to **fake** a post, something allong these lines:

```
// THIS IS AN UNTESTED DRAFT! Just to shown you a direction:
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var scriptname = this.href.replace(/\??(.*)?/, ''); // remove everything after '?'
    var query     = this.href.replace(/(.*)\?/, ''); // remove everything before '?'
    $.post(scriptname, query);
});
```

But again, DONT DO THIS, unless you really REALLY have to. This will send a ajaxcall to the server, so the page wont actually change. Because this is bad practise, im not gonna show you how to make the page change on completion, you'll have to figure this out with the [jQuery POST documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: Add the fact that OP can use Javascript to capture a click on the anchor and force a `POST` via Javascript and you have my upvote ;)

Comment: Haha, was just working on that

Comment: <form method="post" action="zz.php"> <img src="abc.jpg" value="myvalue" onclick="this.form.submit()" name="submited"> </form>

can i use $_POST['submited'] to retrieve on zz.php ?

Comment: Added code about the question based of a form