# Passing $_GET value to $_POST

Tags: php, post, get

Our requirement is to write the variables to a text file in append mode. This can be only partially achieved by the below coding.

First two variable - vuserid and vworkorder are obtained from $_GET, this can be written on the page using ECHO command, however using fwrite + $_POST it is not getting written to File. All Other Variables that are as per user response on the page can be written to the file.

```
<?php  

         $f = fopen("textfile.txt", "a");

         fwrite($f, $_POST["vuserid"] );
         fwrite($f, "|"); 
         fwrite($f, $_POST["vworkorder"]); 
         fwrite($f, "|"); 
         fwrite($f, $_POST["Ques1"]); 
         fwrite($f, "|"); 
         fwrite($f, $_POST["Ques2"]); 
         fwrite($f, "|"); 
         fwrite($f, $_POST["Ques3"]); 
         fwrite($f, "|"); 
         fwrite($f, $_POST["Ques4"]); 
         fwrite($f, "|"); 
         fwrite($f, $_POST["q14"]);
         fwrite($f, ";"); 

     // Close the text file
     fclose($f);              

       echo "Thanks for your Response";     

 ?>
```

Comment: Why would `$_POST` work if they are `$_GET` parameters?

Comment: Can you please provide a bit of code? Not much to do here without a start

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `$_GET` and `$_POST`? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them?lq=1) for instance

Comment: They are both just variable arrays. Show us the conflicting code so we can deduce your problem

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correct, you just want put all variables from $_GET to $_POST?

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $_POST[$key] = $value;
    unset($_GET[$key]);
}

print "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST);
print "</pre>";
```

hope it helps... but at all i think there should be another way to get your vars to your file

Comment: Thanks..let me check this option, My Objective is get the data from the URL and then use $_POST to write that into a FILE in append mode...