# Request activation via HTTP GET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security

In my ASP.Net MVC website, whenever a user registers, the admin should activate his/her account. In my view, I'm creating simple links for this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("activate", "user", new { id = item.ID })"
```

I usually would create a form with a `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` and `POST` it to the controller. However, I think it might be OK to do this via HTTP GET since we're doing this for users which are in `admin` role. Should I use the POST method or is it OK to continue with the HTTP GET and just an `id` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think it might be OK to do this via HTTP GET since we're doing this for users which are in admin role.

Nope. If anyone sends the link to `/user/activate/42` to your admin and he clicks it, he just activated a user.

Apart from the security, read [When should I use GET or POST method? What's the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them) for the implications on HTTP level, which also regards browser implementations (caching, warning for re-post, and the list goes on).

Comment: And that would be the admin's problem. Wouldn't it?

Comment: You don't say "your problem" for security holes you as a developer open.

Comment: I get what you're saying. I guess I was wrong to assume that the admin won't click on any kind of link. I never trust user inputs but I guess I should consider admin a privileged kind of user!

Comment: So what is your suggestion for this? Should I create a form for each row of the table with a separate AntiForgeryToken and a submit button for activation?

Comment: Yes. If you want the action to happen "inline", you can always make it an AJAX link that POSTs the attached form (including anti forgery token).

Answer (score 1):

A GET request should never change the state of the system.  It should leave the system unchanged.  You don't want anyone to be able to approve users by making a GET request as it leaves the system open to attack.  A GET request should also never be used to pass data around.

You should use a PUT request for this ideally.  If you can't use a PUT then a POST is ok.