# Using flask form result to generate a URL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I am creating an app that does some analysis, given a user enters in some IDs into the form. For example, if a user types `12345, 23456` into the TextField form, the app will run some analysis on these IDs and then display the results. My problem is that currently, when the user clicks "Submit" and the data analysis completes, it always redirects the user to `www.website.com/results`. I need to create unique url's like `www.website.com/results/12345+23456` so that 1) I can have multiple users and 2) users can send this link to people to re-generate the analysis.

Now, there are some questions on StackOverflow that are similar to my question but they are not the same and did not help me. So first, let me show some code before discussing that.

I have a home page which contains the the form:

```
    <div>
 <form action="https://website.com/results/" class="form-inline" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="PubmedID">Pubmed ID(s)</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PubmedID" name="pmid" value="{{request.form.pmid}}">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id= "myButton" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

As you can see, the `value` for the form is `request.form.pmid`. My Flask-Wtform for this is here:

```
class pmidForm(Form):
    pmid = TextField('PubmedID')
```

Since the `action` of this form points towards `website.com/results` that triggers my Flask function to be called:

```
@app.route('/results/', methods=["POST"])
def results():
    form = pmidForm()
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':

            #entry = request.form or request.data doesn't help me...
            entry = form.pmid.data #This is the user input from the form! 
            # DO LOTS OF STUFF WITH THE ENTRY 


    return render_template('results.html')

    except Exception as e:
        return(str(e))
```

As you can see I am using `POST` and `form.pmid.data` to get the data from the textfield form.

Again, I don't want to just redirect to `/results`, I'd like to expand on that. I tried to modify my form so that the `form action` pointed to `https://website.com/results/{{request.form.pmid}}/` and then update the results function to be

```
@app.route('/results/<form_stuff>', methods=["POST"])
def results(form_stuff):
```

But this never worked and would re-direct me to a 404 not found page. Which I believe makes sense because there is no form data in the `action` when the HTML is first rendered anyway.

Now, the other post that mine is similar to is: [Keeping forms data in url with flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885937/keeping-forms-data-in-url-with-flask), but it quite doesn't answer or solve my problem. For tthis post, the key point that people made was to use `POST` (which I already do), and to obtain and return the data with `return request.args['query']`. For me, I'm already processing the form data as I need to, and I have my `return render_template()` exactly how I want it. I just need to add something to the `results` URL so that it can be unique for whatever the user put into the form.

What do I need to add to my form in the html and to my Flask `/results` function in order to have the form data added into the URL? Please let me know if there's any other information I can provide to make my problem more clear. I appreciate the help! Thanks

Comment: I would hash the combined ids and use that as the PK for the saved results.

Comment: @Dan can you expand on that? Hash the combined ids with what? A particular python library? Also what do you mean by "PK"?

Comment: Save the results to DB and then redirect to /results/id where id is the PK of the results. You could also use query string params /results/?id=1&id=2 then you lookup the hash of the ids in the db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really a question about Flask.

If you want the data to show in the URL when you submit the form, you should use `method="get"` rather than "post". Then the URL will be in the form https://website.com/results/?pmid=12345.

Comment: That seems like the exact opposite of what was discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885937/keeping-forms-data-in-url-with-flask, which advises to use `post`. Can you explain how its different in my case? I think that I also need `post` in order to deal with the form data inside the results function. I will try `get` and see though, but flask-wtforms works with `post` as I have always used it.

Comment: Update -- you are correct that "get" appended information to the URL, but this results in a 405 "The method is not allowed for the requested URL". Do I need to add something to the @app.route() then?

Comment: Update -- I do not think "get" will work with wtforms. I changed everything to "get" and if I examine the form data it is "None" and class "NoneType". Perhaps then i would change to request.arg?

Comment: Final update -- I changed the form method to "get" and also the method in /results to "get" and then accessed the data as `entry = (request.args.getlist('pmid'))[0]`

Comment: This thread appears to be quite helpful for solving my own code issue. However, I'm stuck with what condition to use to process the form in the route. I've been using `if form.validate_on_submit():` to precede the relevant lines of code but this only works with the POST method. If I change to `if request.method == 'GET'` it makes my else statement redundant as this also uses the GET method. Is there another condition I can use that kicks in when the form is submitted using the GET method?