# Django Form POST with Back button.

Tags: html, django, forms, post

I am submitting a form using `Django`. All things went well until I hit back button. 
This is the time IE displays "`The wab page has expired.` "

I have searched a lot, but can not find the exact concept to do it right.

1. Open page with get request . `/user/search/`
2. Post request with form data on the same page `/user/search/`
3. `[Optional]` Either change params and POST
4. Hit back button.

In both cases you will get webpage Expired. Please guide me how to make this work & avoid the error message?

Comment: On completion of `POST` request on `/user/search/` , redirect using `HttpResponseRedirect` OR `redirect` instead of `reander_to_response` or `HttpResponse` .

Comment: Look, i have my search results in Context_var = {'results': Objects.all()}
If i Redirect it, who would i be able to get this info? I will loose this information right? 
Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: if you are trying to say somthing like this
 `template = loader.get_template('project_list.html')`
  `context = RequestContext(request, {'key', val})`
   `return HttpResponse(template.render(context))`

I have tried it too. it didnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using POST for search forms. POST is for actions that change data on the server. Use GET and you won't have this problem.

Comment: Daniel, Can you please quote or cross reference this? `POST is for actions that change data on the server`
GET has no problem at all, i was just curious about the issue.

Comment: Well, there are plenty of questions here at SO which talk about that: see for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get).