# what does POST stand for in an API header url?

Tags: api, http, post, get, http-headers

I'm trying to access an API with the pattern `POST /api/quotes/params?. . .` and `GET /api/quotes/3` but I don't know what the POST/GET are for. Am I supposed to replace them with something? I understand normal HTTP GET/POST requests but don't see the relevance in this case… please help shed some light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are just normal HTTP methods. Generally, GET requests only fetch data, they don't modify anything on the server. POST requests are used to modify data by submiting a post body.

[When should I use GET or POST method? What's the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them)

They just indicate how you should make your request and/or which methods are available for each endpoint.