# Is there any disadvantage in using POST to retrieve data instead of GET in jQuery Ajax requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

Is there harm ind doing so? Sometimes, I want to retrieve data parameters are too long and I don't want it to show in my URL so I use POST. Should I not be doing this? If so, for the case that I mentioned, how would you go about the long query string?

Comment: Technically, you can do this safely. Semantically, you should use `GET` for requests that simply retrieve information and do not effect a change of state, and `POST` for requests that change the server state in some way.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them

Comment: Do you have a sample `GET` with parameters? Maybe there's a way to refactor your URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inability for caching to take place is one disadvantage. Another is that it may violate the principle of least surprise; people *expect* `GET` for getting data usually.

To avoid a long query string, one approach is to consider whether it makes sense to integrate your parameters into your *path* instead of query string parameters.

Comment: It depends on how long it is. Something longer than 2k may still be reasonable (due to a problem domain) but already causes issues