# Testing simple get request that saves new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I'm new to testing and tried to test a simple get-Request to this Controller-Method:

```
def new
  u = User.new({firstname: 'John',lastname: 'Smith'})
  u.save
end
```

When i request this method through the browser a new User gets created.

Now i tried to test this get request:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe UsersController, :type => :controller do 

    describe 'GET #new' do 

        it "generates a fake User" do 
            expect {get :new}.to change(User, :count).by(1)
        end

    end
end
```

But somehow this test fails i get the message:

```
   expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

What do i wrong? Thanks

Comment: GET is supposed to be idempotent -- in other words, you can issue the same get X times without any side effects. You are not following that "guideline/stricture/rule/whatever". Your GET shouldn't be a GET if you are altering state on the backend. POST is probably your best option, since POST is fairly ambiguous on just what is allowed as the result of a POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John, sending a POST request to #new rather than a GET should clear up that problem. This stack overflow question should help with discerning when to use POST vs GET [When should I use GET or POST method? What's the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them)

As an aside, the convention is to use POST#create to instantiate something and save it to the database in the same function. That way the GET#new renders the new.html.erb view and the 'submit' button on that form actually sends the POST#create with the params that have been entered.