# getParameters keeps returning null

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, servlets

So, I'm having trouble retrieving information from my the client-side jsp. The javascript executes, and the alert prints, however query becomes null in the java servlet, and null is then written to the logger. I can't seem to figure out why the query is now null.

HTML:

```
<div id="query">
    <div id="querybar">
        <form onsubmit="query();return false;" method="get">
        <input type="text" id="querytext" placeholder="Run a query" name="querytext">
        </form>
        <div id="queryimg-container">
            <img src="styles/magnifyingglass.png" id="queryimg" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function query() {
    $.get('QueryHelper', function(data) {
        alert("Somesortofalert");
    });
}
```

Java Servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String query = request.getParameter("querytext");
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    sLogger.info(query);
}
```

Can anyone see anything wrong? I'm super stumped here.

Comment: Please describe what user action you take and then what you observe happening in both client and server.  "trouble retrieving information" is not a complete description of what you observe.

Comment: "I'm having trouble" is not a good description. Please explain what the behavior you experience is, and what is the behavior you expect.

Comment: What are you getting from your ajax call? try to add `.fail(function(){})` to your `$.get` call to see what is wrong...

Comment: @jfriend00 and RealSkeptic. Woops, I skipped that part and pasted my code. Forgot to go back to it. Fixed!

Comment: @albciff The response doesn't seem to fail, adding the .fail(function() {alert("failed)} portion does not seem to do anything. My problem is that getParameter("querytext"); seems to return null, as opposed to the intended return of whatever is in my textbox when I hit enter.

Comment: Your query() function is not submitting anything. It is calling the QueryHelper URL with no parameters and providing a callback. Have a look at the JQuery documentation on how to serialize and post a form.

Comment: @NickVasic Read through the documentation pertaining to **Jonathan Lonowskis** answer, and that totally makes sense. Sorry about that, I'm new to JS/JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be `null` because no parameter by that name is being sent with the Ajax request.

Despite being started by an `onsubmit` event, [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) doesn't have any automatic knowledge of the `<form>`. It's up to you to gather or specify any parameters to be included with the request using the `data` parameter.

```
$.get('QueryHelper', { querytext: 'foo bar' }, function (res) {
    // ...
});
```

Provided you have a reference to the `<form>` or its inputs, you can use [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to prepare the fields' names and values as `data`.

```
<form onsubmit="query(this); return false;" method="get">
<!--                  ^^^^                            -->
```

```
function query(form) {
    //         ^^^^

    $.get('QueryHelper', $(form).serialize(), function (res) {
        //               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        // ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I ended up just using the first part and replacing 'foo bar' with $('#querytext').val(). Does exactly what I want it to do!

Are there any inherent advantages to the second option? Or are they simply two ways of doing it?

Also, isn't this more of a post than a get, as I'm posting things to the servlet? Therefore, shouldn't I change everything to post?

Comment: @Jake In this case, retrieving the single, text field directly is probably simpler. `.serialize()` helps especially with larger forms using multiple input types.

Comment: I assumed that was most likely the difference. Since the serialization solution seems to work, I think I'll just leave it at that. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jake For `GET` vs. `POST`, there are already some posts on SO that can help with choosing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/.